# How Stack overflow updates questions with new activity

Tags: websocket, polling, real-time-updates

I was on a stack overflow page, without refreshing the page shows me that **{number}** questions with new activity, but if i check in Browser network panel, I can't see anything. How they keep on updating this count, without calling any background process.
[image]
Any idea how it happens.

Comment: I observe the same thing after reading your question (no network activity, but the count increases). Very interesting! I'm also curious on how they do it. Could it be that they use push notification?

Comment: Questions about the internal workings of [so] belong on [meta] or [meta.se]. If you're just generally wondering in which ways this could be done (as opposed to how [so] specifically is doing it), this would be too broad.

Comment: I think I have a good guess on how SO achieves this: they use WebSocket. They don't use long polling, because there's no pending XHR connection. They don't use push notification because I have never seen the dialog asking for this. So they must use WebSocket. This Quora answer seems to confirm it: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-websites-that-use-WebSockets > the one about SO